# Shoud I use singular or plural for this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

**"I touched their forehead[s] with my fingertip."**

I'm not certaint whether or not forehead in this example should be singular or plural. There's a group of people, so obviously, multiple foreheads are being touched. However each individual person only has one forehead.

Answer (score 1):

Use plural..............there are multiple objects, even though each person has only one of them.